# slack - webhooks - send image

Tags: curl, webhooks, slack

Dears,

I am trying to write a curl command to send a message via webhook to slack.
The curl should send a image, and the image is located in my local server.

is there anyway to do that ?

here is my code:

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode "payload={\"attachments\":[{\"color\": \"warning\",\"title\":\"Additional Info :\",\"text\":\"\\nLook to the image\",\"image\": \"/image.png\"}]}" https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score -1):

With incoming webhooks you can only send `image_url` which means you need to have that image available online somewhere first.

If you want to "upload" image and send it from server locally you will need Slack Web API and `files.upload` method. That requires a few more steps to get working tho